# I greet the unfortunate, but my occurrence is seldom welcome

Tags: riddle, wordplay, poetry

> My first half is usually sturdy
>   The second is mostly relative
>   If the first is not well maintained
>   I shall greet it with the second

Hint #1

> It doesn’t hurt to give, but it does to receive.

Hint #2

> It is 6 letters long

Hint #3

> Everything in this world can be related with the second half

Comment: [The sincerest form of flattery](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/q/94886/5373)?

Comment: Be my guest, @Randal'Thor :)

Comment: Rand al'Thor, [@BmyGuest](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/users/5840/bmyguest) :-)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think you might be:

> **DAMAGE**

*My first half is usually sturdy*

> A **DAM** must be *sturdy* to hold back enormous volumes of water, form reservoirs and prevent flooding.

*The second is mostly relative*

> People will commonly say that '**AGE** is relative' - "you're only as old as you feel", and all that. (Plus the difference in two people's ages can show who's been alive longer - i.e. it allows a *relative* comparison to be drawn...)

*If the first is not well maintained*
*I shall greet it with the second*

> If a *dam* is poorly maintained it will show signs of *age* and wear...
>
>  (Plus, as the OP prompts in comments, 'greeting' the first half, *dam*, with the second, *age* - i.e. putting them alongside each other - produces *damage*, the direct result of 'not maintaining' the first, i.e. a poorly maintained *dam* will result in *damage*, both to its structure and potentially to the valley and settlements below in the event of it bursting...)

Regarding the hints:

> It does not often hurt the culprit to *damage* someone or something deliberately (through an insult or violence) but it is often physically and mentally scarring for the recipient. 'DAMAGE' is 6 letters long, and everything on our planet has an 'age' as everything has come into existence at some point.

As for the title:

> If you are *unfortunate* enough to encounter something traumatic it may cause you **damage** - but you would never wish for it (it is *unwelcome*).

Comment: Excellent explanation! Just one tiny additon: terrg vg jvgu gur frpbaq pna nyfb zrna *nybat* jvgu gur frpbaq. This is how the two halves can be connected by the whole. Hope you get the picture ;)

Answer (score 3):

There are a few possibilities but I think you may be

> Homesick

My first half is usually sturdy

> Homes are usually sturdy

The second is mostly relative

> Sick can mean cruel and offensive or it can mean excellent so it's meaning is context-dependent (it's relative).

If the first is not well maintained
I shall greet it with the second

> If the home is not well maintained it can lead to illness.

Title

> Homesickness greets people who are far from their home and they seldom welcome it.

Comment: Nice try, but it's not the answer; the second half does not fit too well. Good, you got the poetic aspect of it though (+1)

Answer (score 0):

I doubt this is it as the definitions are still pretty loose.

In a similar vein to [hexominos answer](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/a/94868/7505), are you

> Homework?

My first half is usually sturdy

> Homes are usually safe and strong to protect us from the elements

The second is mostly relative

> The amount of work put into something is relative to the force (effort) and distance (quantity).

If the first is not well maintained
I shall greet it with the second

> If you don't maintain your home you will have to put in a lot of work to improve it.

Also

> Homework is seldom welcome by students and there is nothing worse as a student than to receive lots of homework to do so it's quite 'painful' to receive.

Answer (score -2):

Are you a

> CONCLUSION - a judgment or decision reached by reasoning.

My first half is usually sturdy

> The first half of a CONCLUSION is "a judgement or decision" (and it should be self-evident)

The second is mostly relative

> The second half of a CONCLUSION is the reasoning relative to it.

If the first is not well maintained

> If a CONCLUSION isn't self-evident, it would not be "well maintained". maintain - provide with necessities for life or existence.

I shall greet it with the second

> A CONCLUSION that's not self-evident would require the reasoning behind it to be presented to the recipient. greet - to appear to the perception of